# Umbraco + wordpress

Tags: wordpress, umbraco, umbraco-blog

I've just heard about this umbraco ago and watched the demo on the official website. So is it possible to use it to maintain my wordpress blog? I'm currently using windows live writer where I can download posts, edit them, and upload back. Is it possible to do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. its worse than that. The base coding languages are different too. WordPress on the LAMP stack and Umbraco on .Net MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really. There is an experimental wordpress hive provider for umbraco v5.x, that theoretically would allow umbraco to read/write wordpress data, but its not really something you can just start using - it was more a proof-of-concept demo.

Wordpress is more of a competitor to Umbraco, as opposed to a tool that you would (normally), use in conjunction.

If you are interested, here is the sourcecode of that wordpress provider for umbraco: https://bitbucket.org/boxbinary/hive-wordpress-provider

and here is a blog that discusses it: http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/11/25/a-blob-storage-hive-provider-for-umbraco-5-beta/